# Java bug database: where to send comments that 3 votes is not enough

Tags: java, sun

[Sun's bug database for Java](http://bugs.sun.com/) allows you to vote for up to 3 bugs.

Where can I send feedback that 3 bugs is not enough? (seems like a bug in the bugtracker)

They've left bugs unfixed for years that do not have reasonable workarounds. I'd like to be able to vote for more + have no idea how to push that.

Comment: If you put that bug in the bug tracker, I will unvote for one of my currently voted 3 bugs to vote for your new "need more votes" bug!

Comment: **Oracle** Premier Support for Software?

Comment: @justkt: I started doing that, but there's no appropriate category :-(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about coding, which is what StackOverflow Q&A is for.

Answer (score 6):

Oracle has said that the existing bug database will be replaced with a JIRA for OpenJDK in 2012: [OpenJDK bug database JIRA pilot](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/announce/2011-October/000112.html). The existing bug database probably won't be improved any further. You can provide feedback on the JIRA features on the [OpenJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/discuss)